# how to get an event when the focus is moved out of a node

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML file like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function fontEdit(x, z, y) {
                document.execCommand(x, y, z);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="submit" value="Bold"   onClick="fontEdit('Bold')" />
        <input type="submit" value="Italic" onClick="fontEdit('Italic')" />
        <input type="submit" value="Underline" onClick="fontEdit('Underline')" />
        <input type="submit" value="StrikeThrough" onClick="fontEdit('StrikeThrough')" />
        <div id="EditBox" contentEditable="true" style="width: 600px; height: 200px; border: solid 1px red"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when ever i am moving out of the EditBox, for example clicking on Bold or Italic Button, i want to get an event. Ideally, the Focus Change has to be notified.

Comment: Can you show a simple reproduction of your problem/set-up, over at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be are looking for [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onblur) event of `div`

> The blur event is raised when an element loses focus.

```
<div id="EditBox" contentEditable="true" style="width: 600px; height: 200px; border: solid 1px red" onblur="myFun();"></div>
```

JS

```
function myFun()
{
    alert('you are out of the box.');
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvsrL/)

Comment: Thank you... the same is working for me... i am adding it as an Event Listener.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this to handle Bold,Italic,Underline,Linethrough

```
<input type="submit" value="Bold"   onClick="EditBox.style.fontWeight = 'bold'" />
<input type="submit" value="Italic" onClick="EditBox.style.fontStyle = 'italic'" />
<input type="submit" value="Underline" onClick="EditBox.style.textDecoration = 'underline'" />
<input type="submit" value="StrikeThrough" onClick="EditBox.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'" />
<div id="EditBox" contentEditable="true" style="width: 600px; height: 200px; border: solid 1px red"></div>
```

JS DEMO:- [LINK for JS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nUJvk/)